# Execute script which is on another server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute javascript file which is on another server and get the output of that script from my javascript code. Is there any way of doing this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on what form the output takes. It isn't like JS typically works via STDOUT.

Comment: @Quentin The file which is on another server contains document.write method. Can I get that output in my javascript variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The file which is on another server contains document.write method. Can I get that output in my javascript variable?

Only by overriding `document.write` and then loading the new script.

```
function capture(data) {
    // do something with data
}

document.write = capture;

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://example.com/example.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score -1):

[`$.getScript`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: The file which is on another server contains document.write method. Can I get that output in my javascript variable ?

Comment: You could override `document` with another object having a `write` method that does whatever you want, including storing its argument in a variable.